# Custom listener for Android storage class

Tags: java, android, actionlistener

I am trying to create a custom listener for my storage class. Whenever my storage location will get data the listener will sense that and display a message.

my code is as below,

I created listener interface inside an object,

```
public class mystorageObject
{
    public interface MyCustomStorageContentListener
   {
        public void display();
   }
   MyCustomStorageContentListener listener ;

public mystorageObject()
{
    //doing here the storage initialization things with       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() method

    //listener
    this.listener=null ;
}

public void setCustomListener(MyCustomStorageContentListener eventListener ){

    listener = eventListener ;
}
```

}

And then from my onCreate method of Android activity class I'm using this listener. Initially I am using to test whether it is working but it is not working at all. That is the message "Listener is working" is not getting printed.

```
mystorageObject ob=new mystorageObject() ;
mystorageObject.setCustomListener(new MyCustomStorageContentListener(){
public void display()
{
    Log.v(TAG,"Listener is working");
}
 });
```

Can you please help what I'm missing ? I am trying to learn the custom listener effect so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't shown where you're calling `display`

Comment: Um, you're welcome... did you figure it out then?